# Javascript slider and Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I have a media query that works well, except, when user resize window, the images on the jQuery slider dont resize, until the user manually refreshes the page. I am getting that the slider(http://bxslider.com/) gets the window size when page is rendered and not on the fly. Anyone experienced same thing before?

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you're using jQuery you can check for the window being resized and then reload the slider.

The event hook is:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    //Now reload your slider from the link in your post it seems like it's:
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
}
```

Comment: Works for me but it duplicates the pager, the next/prev buttons, the slider is acting funny, etc.